# Where/How to catch exception happening in a NGXS action?

Tags: angular, exception, state-management, ngxs

I've an Ionic app, which uses NGXS to store the state.

I've started to implement my auth service, which uses firebase behind(with angularfire).

So, basically, I've this action:

```
  @Action(LoginWithPasswordAction)
  async loginWithPassword(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: LoginWithPasswordAction) {
    
      const result = await this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.email, action.password);
      await this.router.navigate(['/']);
    
  }
```

and in the `ngxsOnInit`, I register to the change of authState of angularFire to update the state:

```
  ngxsOnInit(ctx?: StateContext<any>) {
    this.profileSubscription = this.angularFireAuth.authState
      .pipe<Profile>(
        switchMap<User, Observable<Profile>>((user) => {
          if (user) {
            return this.angularFireStore.doc<Profile>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
          } else {
            return of(null);
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe((profile) => {
        const formatedProfile = profile ? this.formatFromFirebase(profile) : null;
        ctx.patchState({
          profile: formatedProfile,
          loaded: profile !== null          
        });
      });
  }
```

This work perfectly when I login successfully.

Now, I've to manage the error case. Currently if I use a wrong password, firebase throws an exception.

I was kind of expecting to be able to "catch" it where I dispatch the action, in my sign-in component:

```
  async login() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      try {
        await this.store.dispatch(
          new LoginWithPasswordAction(this.loginForm.get('email').value, this.loginForm.get('password').value)
        );
        this.navController.navigateRoot('/');
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
        this.loginError = ex.message;
      }
    }
  }
```

But I don't receive the exception, I guess because NGXS catch it for me(in the logs, I see the error coming from NGXS-logger-plugin)

So:
**In the NGXS concept, where/how should the exception happening in the action be caught/handled?**

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer.

There is apparently two way of catching the exception according to the documentation(my bad): https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/errors

Within the action

```
  @Action(HandledError)
  handledError(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>) {
    try {
      // error is thrown
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error catched inside @Action wont propagate to ErrorHandler or dispatch subscription')
    }
  }
```

or where you dispatch the action:

```
  @Action(UnhandledError)
  unhandledError(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>) {
    // error is thrown, DO NOT CATCH IT
  }



  unhandled() {
    this.store.dispatch(new UnhandledError()).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.log('unhandled error on dispatch subscription')
        return of('')
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Apparently, it's prefered to catch the exception in the action, and update the state with it.